# Background GPS in iOS. Is this possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gps, core-location

I was wondering if it was possible to get the location of the iPhone with an app that isnt running, or at least running in the background.  What I want to do is have the iPhone send a push notification when it arrives at a certain coordinate.  Is this possible?  If so, could someone put me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: There are some good answers here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465929/how-to-track-user-location-in-background

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Your application can ask to be notified of significant location changes or to simply continue using the GPS while executing in the background. The former—the approach recommended by Apple—uses less power at the cost of accuracy ([this](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/) blog post indicates that the updates are accurate to roughly 500m), while the latter is as accurate as the device can manage. This is all detailed in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) and and the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).

If you simply want your application to be notified when the device moves into a particular region, you may want to look into `CLLocationManager`'s [`startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html). If the device moves into a particular geographical region, your app is launched (even if it's not running!).

Comment: been 58s slower than you, just deleted my similar but shorter answer ;)

Comment: @Vincent, I know how you feel sometimes.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this was possible. Good to know.