# iOS - CLLocationManager background operation with MKMapView in foreground

Tags: ios, location

The question "Background GPS in iOS. Is this possible?" does not answer this question.

I have a mapping app that uses `MKMapView` and its built-in location services when the app is active. When the app is in the background, I would still like location updates to be delivered and processed. For that, I'm using `CLLocationManager`.

I have `location updates` enabled in the plist file and call `startUpdateLocation` in the `AppDelegate` code which also acts as the delegate for `CLLocationManager`. This is everything mentioned in "Background GPS in iOS. Is this possible?",

When the app is active, everything works okay, getting updates no problem.

But when put in background mode, the little arrow indicating location services are being used comes on, but then disappears after about ten seconds. In this brief time period, the app seems to be able to receive location updates, but when the arrow is gone, no more updates.

Am I doing something wrong? Does `MKMapView` override what `CLLocationManager` wants to do?

Comment: Hi Russell, your question may have already been answered [in this duplicate, or closely related, question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526403/background-gps-in-ios-is-this-possible)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - Please read the question carefully, you'll see that I am doing everything stated in that reference. Please remove the close request, if you added it.

Comment: @Krumelur - Okay, that's what I thought, no need to optimize there.

Comment: @Krumelur - have revised the code, still exhibiting the same behaviour - revised the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure "Background App Refresh" is enabled in your settings. You can check this programmatically by using `backgroundRefreshStatus` of `UIApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

To receive location updates in the background, do the following:

- Make sure to have a **started** `CLLocationManager`
- Make sure to have the following value in your `info.plist`:
  "Required background modes" = "App registers for location updates"
- Avoid doing a lot of complicated things in your `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation`. In particular, avoid UI operations. Your execution time is limited by iOS, and not all APIs are available.

Everything is well documented, see "Getting Location Events in the Background" in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).