# Getting coordinates of GPS all the time, even if the app is closed iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, gps

I am building a security app to notify people around some area that an accident or problem has occurred near to them.

To locate if the users are near to the area i need to get the coordinates every 10 minutes, but i can't guarantee that my users will have the app opened all the time, so, is there any way of keep sending the coordinates to my server even if my app is closed or the iphone is locked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526500/2199538)

You also have the official apple doc that explains that [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

Consider maybe using the significant location change in order to save battery life. It is user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

See 'implementing Long Running Tasks'